# How to set up a Scrapy proxy with authorization?

Tags: scrapy

My middlewares settings:

```py
from w3lib.http import basic_auth_header 
class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = "111.11.11.111:1111"
        request.headers['Proxy - Authorization'] = basic_auth_header('login', 'password')
```

My settings:

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'my_project.middlewares.CustomProxyMiddleware': 350,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 400,
}
```

After launching, I get an error:

```
scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11.TunnelError: Could not open CONNECT tunnel with proxy 217.29.53.106:51725 [{'status': 407, 'reason': b'Proxy Authentication Required'}]
```

What is the reason, how to fix it? (I use valid https proxies)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the header name to be `Proxy-Authorization`

```
request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = basic_auth_header('login', 'password')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy = [
  'http': 'http://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}',
  'https': 'https://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}',
]

yield scrapy.request(url=url, proxy=proxy}
```

doesn't this work?